# My Nexus 6P becomes very slow when i'm running the android AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Hi my Nexus 6P becomes very slow when i'm running the android AVD? The AVD gets quite slow sometimes as well.  Its a Nexus 6P API 18 android version 4.3. Please guide me that what could be causing this priblem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your RAM is not enough. I suggest you have a check, because Android Studio need lots of memory, so does AVD.

Comment: yea i thought so.. i have 4 gb of ram, is there any way i can speed up the avd?

Comment: @SteveX add more RAM, I think.

Comment: yea thanks for the help.. i figured my ram wasnt enough  i was just wondering if there is a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Your RAM seems to be not be enough for running Android Studio and AVD, since both are memory-hogging processes. You could free up some memory by clearing unwanted processes using Task Manager in Windows(Ctrl+Shift+Del) or use GenyMotion. GenyMotion is much faster than the usual AVD.